# My 'control-label' is out of the margin-left automatic from the 'form-group' (bootstrap 3)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

He's all aligned, but the label is getting 'stuck' on page side.
I tried using 'margin-left' but then he distorted everything else.

[image]

I want the result to be like this:

[image]

Below is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/vzm7et7z/1/

---

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <form id="form-sms" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="salva.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="operadora">OPERADORA</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select id="operadora" name="operadora" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Selecione uma operadora</option>
                                <option value="CLARO">Claro</option>
                                <option value="CTBC">CTBC</option>
                                <option value="OI">Oi</option>
                                <option value="NEXTEL">Nextel</option>
                                <option value="TIM">TIM</option>
                                <option value="VIVO">Vivo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ddd_destinatario">DESTINATÁRIO</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select id="ddd_destinatario" name="campoDDD_d" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">DDD</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="51">51</option><option value="52">52</option><option value="53">53</option><option value="54">54</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="56">56</option><option value="57">57</option><option value="58">58</option><option value="59">59</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="61">61</option><option value="62">62</option><option value="63">63</option><option value="64">64</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="66">66</option><option value="67">67</option><option value="68">68</option><option value="69">69</option><option value="70">70</option><option value="71">71</option><option value="72">72</option><option value="73">73</option><option value="74">74</option><option value="75">75</option><option value="76">76</option><option value="77">77</option><option value="78">78</option><option value="79">79</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="81">81</option><option value="82">82</option><option value="83">83</option><option value="84">84</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="86">86</option><option value="87">87</option><option value="88">88</option><option value="89">89</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="91">91</option><option value="92">92</option><option value="93">93</option><option value="94">94</option><option value="95">95</option><option value="96">96</option><option value="97">97</option><option value="98">98</option><option value="99">99</option>            
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="telefone_destinatario" name="campoCEL_d" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="9" class="form-control input-md numerico" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Text input-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nome">SEU NOME</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input id="nome" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Select Basic -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ddd_remetente">SEU NÚMERO</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <select id="ddd_remetente" name="campoDDD_r" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">DDD</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="51">51</option><option value="52">52</option><option value="53">53</option><option value="54">54</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="56">56</option><option value="57">57</option><option value="58">58</option><option value="59">59</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="61">61</option><option value="62">62</option><option value="63">63</option><option value="64">64</option><option value="65">65</option><option value="66">66</option><option value="67">67</option><option value="68">68</option><option value="69">69</option><option value="70">70</option><option value="71">71</option><option value="72">72</option><option value="73">73</option><option value="74">74</option><option value="75">75</option><option value="76">76</option><option value="77">77</option><option value="78">78</option><option value="79">79</option><option value="80">80</option><option value="81">81</option><option value="82">82</option><option value="83">83</option><option value="84">84</option><option value="85">85</option><option value="86">86</option><option value="87">87</option><option value="88">88</option><option value="89">89</option><option value="90">90</option><option value="91">91</option><option value="92">92</option><option value="93">93</option><option value="94">94</option><option value="95">95</option><option value="96">96</option><option value="97">97</option><option value="98">98</option><option value="99">99</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input id="telefone_remetente" name="campoCEL_r" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="9" class="form-control input-md numerico" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="campoSMS">MENSAGEM</label>
                        <div class="col-md-8 control-zero">
                            <textarea name="campoSMS" id="campoSMS" class="form-control textarea-sms" maxlength="100"></textarea>
                            <p class="help-block textarea-contagem"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-4 control-zero">
                            <button id="enviar" name="enviar" class="btn btn-enviar">ENVIAR!</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

---

CSS:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label{
    /* text-align:right; */
    height: 34px;
    text-align:left;
    background: #A0D468;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.btn-form {
    padding: 0;
}

.btn-enviar {
    background: #8e44ad;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.btn-enviar:hover {
    background: #BE90D4;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the column structure of Bootstrap CSS. Right now, you have:

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
<div class="col-md-8"></div>
```

Which makes the perfect `col-md-12` for fullsize view. When you shrink this, it doesn't know how to handle the overflow, which is why the first `col-md-4` appears in the wrong spot above the input. You're gonna want to look into `visibile-sm, visible-xs, hidden-md` etc classes of Bootstrap and design a separate layout for smaller devices. For example:

```
<div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <label>Example:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="example" class="form-control" value=""/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <label>Example:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col=md-8 col-lg-8">
      <input type="text" name="example" class="form-control" value=""/>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Will render different designs for the same element depending on the size of the browser. Hopefully that can give you some insight, but it's up to you to figure out how you want your website/application laid out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>` to

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="control-label"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use style="margin-left:15px;" with labels, its working fine, i have tested

Comment: That doesn't work... He tried this, said it didn't work. Read the question.

Comment: @Tim: yes Tim that is why i am asking him to do inline styling in label tag rather putting this margin-left in internal css

Comment: If he does that, it affects his view on larger devices... He's just trying to get the labels in the right place (aka margin-left:15px) when the view is a certain size, not all the time. That's why this isn't viable.

Comment: yes Tim you are right, let's see whether it also fits on other sizes or not.
what do you suggest, shall he use media queries to cater this issue.

Comment: It's just that he's using inline elements on `md` size, but wants them stacked on `sm` and `xs`, which isn't going to work on its own. He needs to use some kind of media query or `visible.*` in Bootstrap to catch that.